# How to use one transformation affects multiple things on a context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw multiple things on a canvas with different transformation. I'm applying a.scale() just for berzierCurveTo() part but the scale transformation affects the arc() at the bottom as well. I've already tried closePath() and resetting scale(1,1) but it wouldn't do anything. What should I do?

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var a = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = 500;
c.height= 550;
//Shape 1 with some transformations

a.scale(0.8,0.8); //How come a.scake affects the shape 2 as well?
a.beginPath();
a.moveTo(143, 59);
a.bezierCurveTo(151, 51, 195, 7, 272, 22);
a.stroke();
a.closePath();  //closePath doesn't do anything to stop scaling the shape 2

//Shape 2
a.beginPath();
a.arc(250, 400, 100, 0,6.3, false);
a.stroke();
```

[This is what the image looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/5J9WZ)

Comment: Do you want scaling for shape2 as done in shape1?

Comment: no but I want different type of transformation, I don't want same scaling on shape 2

Comment: You can use `scale` for shape 2 like `a.scale(2,2);a.beginPath();a.arc(250, 400, 100, 0,6.3, false);a.stroke();`

Comment: TemporaryNickName Is acting like he is me!

Answer (score 1):

You can save canvas state before scaling and restore it after shape 1:

```
a.save();

a.scale(0.8, 0.8);
a.beginPath();
a.moveTo(143, 59);
a.bezierCurveTo(151, 51, 195, 7, 272, 22);
a.stroke();
a.closePath();

a.restore();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq5mR/